# Modifying the default ExpansionTile children vertical padding Flutter

Tags: flutter, widget, flutter-layout

**How can I reduce the vertical padding between the ExpansionTile children:** 
[image]

**Here is the inline widget code:**

```
Expanded(
    child: ListView(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(0.0) ,
        primary: true,
        shrinkWrap: true,
        children: <Widget>[
            ExpansionTile(
                title: Text("Categories"),
                children: [
                    CheckboxListTile(
                        controlAffinity: ListTileControlAffinity.trailing,
                        title: Text( "Cars", maxLines: 1, ),
                      ),
                    CheckboxListTile(
                        controlAffinity: ListTileControlAffinity.trailing,
                        title: Text("Veichle", maxLines: 1, ),
                      ),
                    ],
                initiallyExpanded: true,
                ),
        ],
    ),
),
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By adding A `ListTileTheme` before each `ExpansionTile` and making `dense: true,` 

it will make Padding more **"Reasonable"**

```
Expanded(
    child: ListView(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(0.0) ,
        primary: true,
        shrinkWrap: true,
        children: <Widget>[
           ListTileTheme(
           dense: true,
           child: ExpansionTile(
                title: Text("Categories"),
                children: [
                    CheckboxListTile(
                        controlAffinity: ListTileControlAffinity.trailing,
                        title: Text( "Cars", maxLines: 1, ),
                      ),
                    CheckboxListTile(
                        controlAffinity: ListTileControlAffinity.trailing,
                        title: Text("Veichle", maxLines: 1, ),
                      ),
                    ],
                initiallyExpanded: true,
                ),
          ),
        ],
    ),
)
```